# Chrome not showing "content" in the inspector Network tab

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes the Chrome Inspector shows "Size/Content" in the Network Tab and sometimes it only shows "Size".  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few wasted hours, I realized Chrome has a **"Use small resource rows"** and **"Use large resource rows"** options.  This setting may change depending on what site you are visiting / what you had set last.  It is not very obvious, but when this is checked, the Network Tab will only show "Size".  When it is disabled, you will see "Size" and "Content" (which is useful when trying to see the compressed size of downloaded files over HTTP).

[image]